# package.json vs config.xml for cordova plugins

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

## What is the right way to manage Cordova's plugins & platforms ?

On a project using `cordova@5.4.0` & `ionic-cli@1.7.8`, I face 2 possibilities:

### with Cordova (config.xml)

```sh
cordova create dummy-project && cd dummy-project
cordova platform add browser --save
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device --save

## If forgot to add `--save` option, manually update config.xml
#cordova platform save
#cordova plugin save

# reset platforms & plugins, like we just checked out the repository
rm -rf platforms plugins

# `cordova prepare` automatically setup platforms & plugins
# dependencies via config.xml
cordova prepare
```

**Pros**

- Platforms and plugins belong to the *Cordova realm*, so it seems intuitive to use cordova
- Platforms and plugins versions are saved in `config.xml` like below:

  ```
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.0.1" />
  <engine name="browser" spec="~4.0.0" />
  ```
- Multiple developers who checkouts the repo will get the same dependencies

**Cons**

- Yet another config file `config.xml` which clutters the project's root directory
- Duplicate infos in `plugins/fetch.json` and `platforms/platforms.json` ?
- *Must explicitly add `--save` option*

### with Ionic (package.json)

```sh
ionic start dummy-project blank && cd dummy-project
ionic platform add browser
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-device

# reset platforms & plugins, like we just checked out the repository
rm -rf platforms plugins

# fetch platforms & plugins dependencies via package.json
ionic state restore
```

### Pros

- Project's dependencies consolidated into `package.json` with the following  custom keys:

  - `cordovaPlugins`
  - `cordovaPlatforms`
- *Autosave* behaviour when adding a platform or plugin

### Cons

- No version pinning for plugins nor platforms in package.json *(that's a huge blocker for me)*
- Why not put cordova plugins & platforms into `dependencies` since they are NPM packages anyway ?
  `ionic` could symlink the dependancies between `node_modules` & `{plugins,platforms}/`

Are the ionic & cordova developers considering a unification/refactorisation of this matter ?

Comment: I personally keep my cordova-cli and ionic-cli@beta updated, and use `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-name --save` and it works for me (should update both the dependencies)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Edit: second update! 2017.05.**

It changes again - this time on Cordova side.
Cordova 7 adds support for `package.json`!

See on Cordova blog: http://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/05/04/cordova-7.html

**Edit: update 2016.05.**

It seems that many `ionic` commands were created due to lack of the features in `cordova`, but since cordova caught up and implemented many new features, the ionic maintainers are considering dumping their command like `ionic state` in favor of the ones provided by cordova.

So it seems that going the "cordova way" might be more future-proof.

See those tickets:

- https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/904
- https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1324

**Original answer (2016.03.):**

It's a matter of person taste I'd say. Whatever solution you go through, it's best to be consistent and then always use `cordova plugin add ...` or `ionic plugin add` and not mix the two.

FYI you can have version pinning with ionic's solution, but true, you have to put it manually, or you have to specify the version explicitly during installation e.g. `ionic plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard@1.0.8`. Definitely there's room for improvements in ionic CLI regarding that.

For example, this is our `package.json` with pinned plugin versions and platform versions as well, and also pinned github SHA1:

```
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard@1.0.8",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@1.2.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-push@1.5.3",
    {
      "locator": "https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent.git#3d12378de9f38be900761a0ad06ab697cf6d9add",
      "id": "com.borismus.webintent"
    },
    {
      "variables": {
        "APP_ID": "123456789987654321",
        "APP_NAME": "TEST"
      },
      "locator": "cordova-plugin-facebook4@1.6.3",
      "id": "cordova-plugin-facebook4@1.6.3"
    }
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "android@4.1"
  ]
```

Then when you do `ionic state restore` it will honor the versions listed.

Comment: I updated the answer with some info from ionic team that radically changes the answer.

Comment: the relevant ionic ticket was changed to https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1324 on 2016-08-31

Answer (score 3):

i would try using `ionic state save` and `ionic state restore` to manage the configuration including plugins... See documentation for more information