# Can we just add Cordova plugins to package.json?

Tags: javascript, cordova, webview, cordova-plugins, package.json

When do we need to save a plugin in config.xml?

Normally we use `cordova plugin add <plugin-name>` to add and save the plugin into our `package.json`

The [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#plugin) says that those plugins into `config.xml` will be restored during a **prepare**.
What does this mean? Can we just set plugins in one place? Is there any problem having plugins only in package.json?
Also [I checked previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830058/package-json-vs-config-xml-for-cordova-plugins) but it's still confusing me.

Thank you so much for your time : )
Note: I'm using Cordova 9.0.0

Answer (score 1):

> Cordova 9.0.0 no longer uses config.xml as the source of plugin (or
>   platform) data/versions.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-docs/issues/1004

Now, everything is just in one place : ) in `package.json` so we can remove platforms and plugins from `config.xml`

Comment: It seems phonegap doesn't recognize the plugins from package.json, though the cli is also 9.0. Do you know a workaround for this? Thank